# Why the "if" gets ignored in this Google apps script?

Tags: dictionary, calendar

I am trying to get a spreadsheet to update a calendar on my Google account, but I am struggling to get the `if` condition on the code below to work. When I run `inseritoNelCal` the debug says that it is unspecified even though the spreadsheet has actually data in each row/column.

```
    var IN_CAL = new String('INSERITO');

    function dallaTabellaAlCalendario() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process

    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);

    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[0]; // First column
    var startTime = new Date(row[1]); // 2nd column
    var endTime = new Date(row[02]); // 3rd column
    var description = row[3]; // 4th column
    var location = row[4]; // 5th column
    var guests = row[5]; // 6th column
    var inseritoNelCal = row[6]; // 7th column
    }

    if (inseritoNelCal != IN_CAL){


 var calendar CalendarApp.getCalendarById("mycalendarID").createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, {Descrizione: description, Luogo: location, Allievi: guests, Inserito: inseritoNelCal });
    sheet.getRange(startRow, 7).setValue(IN_CAL);

    }
    }
```